# Twilio-video connection (getUserMedia is not supported) in google chrome, iPhone

Tags: twilio, twilio-video

I am using twilio-video 2.7.2 and while trying to connect video call in iPhone chrome browser it is getting error like below attached screenshot.

can anyone please suggest me how overcome this issue.

[2.72](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aO3H.png)

Comment: Please improve your question, add screenshots, examples, code blocks if needed .. etc
it's hard to help you.
you can also read StackOverflow guide how to write a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple iOS does not expose WebRTC API's to third party browsers. Use Mobile Safari.

[Supported Browsers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/javascript#supported-browsers)

"* Chrome and Firefox for iOS do not have access to WebRTC APIs, unlike Safari for iOS."